# Create a Plus Symbol (+) with an SVG Path

Tags: google-maps-api-3, svg, google-polyline

Im trying to create a + sign as an SVG path for a google maps project. The plus symbol will be plotted along a polyline using the Icon path property. So far I've manage to get close, my plus symbol currently looks like a horizontal line with the vertical set at one end "-|". I need it to appear in the middle of the horizontal line to make it look like a plus.

My current path is set using the following path command:

```
path: 'M 0,-1 0,1 H -1,1 0,1'
```

How should I alter this to achieve my plus symbol? I can find lots of examples for much more complex shapes, curves, gradient fills and such forth but with my limited knowledge Im struggling to find the correct coordinates to express my shape!

Comment: Could you use a text element instead of a path and then just render a plus character?

Comment: I'd not thought of that - any idea of the syntax?

Comment: No idea but taking a wild guess if you are doing `var x = { path: 'M 0,-1 0,1 H -1,1 0,1', strokeColor: '#f00' }` for example then maybe `var x = { text: '+', strokeColor: '#f00' }` ?

Comment: Doesnt seem to support text as a property sadly, this would have been great but doesnt seem to be supported!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think what you want is:

`path: 'M0,-1 V1 M-1,0 H1'`

Which translates as start at (0, -1), draw vertically 1 unit, then move to (-1, 0) and draw horizontally 1 unit.

Comment: Ahhh thanks for that, spot on and much more succinct! Works like a charm. Could you recommend any good online resources for testing paths and such forth as Ive got quite a few little paths I need to produce and reloading my app every time I make a change is a bit of a pain? Very much obliged!

Comment: I don't know of anything quite like that. I have made something somewhat similar in that you can drag points of some existing paths and see the code: http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/svg-tutorial/paths. Perhaps I'll try to make something where you can add new paths and nodes.

Comment: Hey thanks for the tip and your post Ill definitely be reading and using that! ;o)

Answer (score 0):

Whilst Im fairly sure this isn't the most succinct way  to describe this path Ive managed to construct a plus sign using the following path statement [More by trial and error and some very fuzzy memories of Turtle]:

```
path: 'M 0,0 H 0.5,0.5 1,1 M 0,0 V 0.5,0.5 1,1 M 0,0 H -0.5,-0.5 -1,-1 M 0,0 V -0.5,-0.5 -1,-1',
```